# Need help regarding Image Processing App

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, image-manipulation

I am developing one image processing app for iPad. In which I am using different sliders for applying different effect on some image.

My problem is how can I save the state of any slider?

Suppose I changed Hue slider and then Brightness slider and then Contrast slider, and again I go back to Hue Slider and changed it, Here i need to save the state so only Hue effect become change in image and rest Brightness and Contras looks same as it is.

I have around 10 sliders for different effects like: Brightness, Contrast, Hue, RGB, Blur, Vignette... etc. All are working perfectly independently, not together. I need that they all should work together.

Comment: i Have around 10 sliders for different effects like: Brightness, Contrast, Hue, RGB, Blur, Vignette...etc. All are working perfectly independently not together. And i need that they all should work together.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, when you need to apply the effect, you're going to respond on the sliders' actions to get their values and pass them to your effects function.

Remember these values that you pass in some class, either in the ViewController, or better, in the model layer.

Comment: I am already passing these value in some other class. But still no success. Can you please explain exactly what you mean by this when you say These values that you pass in some class...in the model layer ?